# How to use three js write?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to work on project that uses three.js. So I have tried to learn the basic and O wrote this simple code just to see something. But it doesn't work at all and when I click to view it on web browser nothing is shown.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Three.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">4
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(document.body.clientWidth,
                         document.body.clientHeight);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        renderer.setClearColorHex(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
        renderer.clear();

        // new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( FOV, viewAspectRatio, zNear, zFar );
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 10000);
        camera.position.z = 300;

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50),
                       new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 }));
        scene.add(cube);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't it work? What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What's with jquery 1.5.1? Why not use the current release?

Comment: i will use it, i just learning the basic of three js now

Answer (score 0):

Good day, could you tell us what version of Three.js your using (it shows up in the console once it loads if your not sure), and what browser your using?

A few notes, `renderer.setClearColorHex` is deprecated now, this should be just `renderer.setClearColor`.

Also you set the Camera with `width / height` but I dont see them defined anywhere?

Next is the `camera.position.z = 300;` may be too far away to see a little cube at (0, 0, 0)

Try those items and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just see this example.
http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube

You are missing a main loop for cosecutive frame rendering. Also as Darryl said, what is width and height?